# Using class methods in another file not working in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to include a class in PHP and to use the methods from this class in another file. My code looks like that (small reproducable example). By the way: I'm working on a WordPress environment.

Main file:

```
include 'class-file.php';

$cars = new Cars();
var_dump($cars->getCars());
```

File `class-file.php`:

```
class Cars {

  public function getCars() {
    return "No Cars";
  }

}
```

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Cars::load() in /..../wp-content/themes/builder/includes/elements.php
```

Seems that my class instance is connected with another class from the theme. But why? Can I disconnect the class from any others? If yes, how?

Comment: We need more context here. The posted example doesn't give us much to go on and isn't where the error is thrown (since it fails on a different method than you're using in your example). Where are you files located? Where in the code are you including the file and creating the class instance? And what do you do with the instance after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the theme doesn't use [namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php), which makes all its classes discoverable from the global namespace, and by defining your own `Cars` class, you override the theme's class.

Try to define your namespace, and check if the conflict is gone.

Main file:

```php
include 'class-file.php';

$cars = new \mycode\Cars();
var_dump($cars->getCars());
```

File `class-file.php`:

```php
namespace mycode;

class Cars {

  public function getCars() {
    return "No Cars";
  }

}
```